# solid black screen while upgrading ubuntu from 15.10 to 16.04

Tags: xubuntu

I was upgrading my Ubuntu from 15.10 to 16.04. Suddenly my screen turned grayish and I waited for 5 minutes still there was no change. Then I forced shutdown my laptop and when I restarted it I am getting a solid blackscreen and can't even use Win 7 ( dual boot). Please help what to do. Tried pressing <kbd>f1</kbd>, <kbd>f9</kbd>, <kbd>f12</kbd>, <kbd>esc</kbd>, <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>f1</kbd> , etc still nothing is happening. Please help...

Comment: Sounds like GRUB was destroyed. Try booting from a live DVD and run the boot repair program.

Comment: Sorry for replying soooooo late. The problem was of RAM. My system's RAM got crashed. I tried replacing with other RAM and my system was running fine this time. Even googling the above condition will show you that the above problem is associated with the RAM.
Thanks to all for help.

Answer (score 0):

Try to get your Windows/Ubuntu installation back by using the **boot-repair** tool with an Ubuntu Live DVD/USB.

First, boot into Ubuntu Live. Enable internet access, open terminal (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) and enter these commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && boot-repair
```

boot-repair GUI will popup, try to repair, see if Windows is listed in grub then reboot.

Comment: At that time I could nothing. I tried above. The problem was with the RAM. Updating UBUNTU crashed my RAM :(